# Is this code actually multithreaded?

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Goal:** Spin up 20 threads that will all hit the `SessionFactory.GetSessionFactory(key)` method at the same time for testing purposes. (I'm trying to simulate a multi-threaded environment such as ASP.NET)

**Question:** By using the `EndInvoke()` method am I essentially calling the `GetSessionFactory(key)` method synchronously or is my code correct in simulating multiple threads all hitting `GetSessionFactory(key)` at the same time?

Thanks,

Kyle

```
public void StressGetSessionFactory()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Func<string, ISessionFactory> method = GetSessionFactory;
        IAsyncResult asyncResult = method.BeginInvoke("RBDB", null, null);
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = method.EndInvoke(asyncResult); //My concern is with this call

        Debug.WriteLine("RBDB ISessionFactory ID: " + sessionFactory.GetHashCode());
    }

}

static ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory(string key)
{
    return SessionFactory.GetSessionFactory(key);
}
```

Comment: Just click the green check-mark under said best answers :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
IAsyncResult asyncResult = method.BeginInvoke("RBDB", null, null);
ISessionFactory sessionFactory = method.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
```

It's not parallel, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> The EndInvoke method is used to
>   retrieve the results of the
>   asynchronous call. It can be called
>   any time after BeginInvoke; if the
>   asynchronous call has not completed,
>   EndInvoke will block until it
>   completes.

To make parallel calls you could use a higher level abstraction (like the TPL i.e. would give you all of this almost for free) or slightly refactor your code - make the asynchronous calls first, then collect the results afterwards (untested):

```
IAsyncResult[] asyncResult = new IAsyncResult[20];
ISessionFactory[] sessionFactories = new ISessionFactory[20];
Func<string, ISessionFactory> method = GetSessionFactory;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    asyncResult[i] = method.BeginInvoke("RBDB", null, null);
}
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    sessionFactories[i] = method.EndInvoke(asyncResult[i]); 
}
```

Note that with `BeginInvoke()` you do not have a guarantee that you are in fact making 20 calls in parallel, since it uses the thread pool it will parallelize as it sees fit.

Comment: A better way would be to pass a callback method into BeginInvoke, and have it call the Debug.Writeline.   Just make sure that you call EndInvoke inside the callback function.